# Why does gcc gives me maybe-uninitialized warning for deque::insert with a filtered range

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++14, deque

Why does gcc gives me maybe-uninitialized warning for `deque::insert` with a filtered range when compiling with `-O2` and `-DNDEBUG`

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>

auto foo(){
    std::deque<int> d{3,4};
    std::vector<int> v{0,2};
    auto b = 1;
    using boost::adaptors::filtered;
    auto r = v | filtered([&b](auto i){return i>b;});

    d.insert(std::end(d),r.begin(),r.end());
    return d;
}
```

Compiler gcc 9.2 , flag `-std=c++2a -O2 -Wall -Werror  -DNDEBUG`

This is the warning:

```
<source>: In member function 'void std::deque<_Tp, <source>: In member function 'void std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _ForwardIterator = boost::iterators::filter_iterator<boost::range_detail::default_constructible_unary_fn_wrapper<foo()::<lambda(auto:1)>, bool>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >; _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]':

<source>:10:48: error: '*((void*)& __mid +16)' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]

   10 |     auto r = v | filtered([&b](auto i){return i>b;});

      |                                               ~^~

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/deque:69,

                 from <source>:1:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-9.2.0/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/deque.tcc:793:24: note: '*((void*)& __mid +16)' was declared here

  793 |       _ForwardIterator __mid = __first;

      |                        ^~~~~

<source>:10:48: error: '*((void*)& __mid +16)' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]

   10 |     auto r = v | filtered([&b](auto i){return i>b;});

      |
```

If `b` is captured by value, then the warning is gone.

https://godbolt.org/z/8Tbfgf

Comment: Just a compiler bug. Note that gcc 8 does not warn anymore.

Comment: +1 for compiler bug.  If you change the lambda to just capture everything by reference `[&]` the error goes away too, so it's confused as to the initialization state of the named capture...

Comment: Note that in this warning, "uninitialized" can also mean "after its destruction".

Comment: This warning has always been (still is) very fragile. In particular, it often triggers on dead code that the compiler doesn't notice is dead, and that dead code can easily be something that the compiler itself produced by inlining, unrolling, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are capturing a compile time constant by reference.

```
filtered([](auto i){return i>b;})
```

that is [legal](https://godbolt.org/z/vWvXJa), because a `const auto b = 1` is a compile time constant you can use without referencing.

The compiler is getting confused by the unused reference to a compile time constant being captured by name.  It probably optimizes out said capture, because a reference that is never used can be skipped.  Which leaves you with an uninitialized capture `b`, which other code confuses with the compile-time value of the same name, and you get your warning.

This is obviously a compiler bug.  It should probably instead warn you something like:

> ```
> variable captured but unused
> ```

or something similar.

Comment: @ZhengQu `const auto b = 1` *is* a compile time constant.

Comment: @ZhengQu Consider when contradicting someone to doubt yourself before expressing it with certainty.  ;)  It may only be a compile time constant for legacy reasons, but it is indeed a compile time constant.  C++ has quirks.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I apologize. I must be misunderstanding something. Can you please tell me what the definition of `compile time constant` is? Some links to documentations would also be appreciated.

Comment: @ZhengQu the definition of "usable in constant expressions" is here: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3.

Comment: I get the same warning if b is not a constant expression https://godbolt.org/z/6CWUYU